# Getting "error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' to 'const char*' error while passing a path as argument

Tags: c++

I want to access all the directories and subdirectories from the default installed directory, but it is failing in traversing the folder. Here I am passing the path to a constant char. Below is the code

```
using namespace std;

int reading(const char *d_path)
{
    cout << "In Reading" << endl;

    /* bfs::path pathSource("c:\\Program Files\\"); */
    struct stat info; //

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    dir = opendir(d_path);
    cout << dir << endl;
    if ((dir = opendir(d_path)) != NULL)
    {
        cout << "in IF" << endl;
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
        {
           if (ent->d_name[0] != NULL)
           {
               cout << "New" << endl;
               string path = string (d_path) + string(ent->d_name) + '\\';
               cout << "Entry = " << path << endl;
               stat (path, &info);
               if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
               {
                   reading(path);
               }
           }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    /* Print all the files and directories within directory */

    else
    {
        /* Could not open directory */
        perror("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Advice -- you could have easily produced a [simple function that demonstrated the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c912eafdc46aeac).  Now that you see that example, do you see why the error is given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `string::c_str()` method, like `stat(path.c_str())`, to convert a C++ string to a C string.

See *[std::string::c_str](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)* for more information.